# Gas energy dissipation causing collapse

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, radiation, gas, cooling

Why is the dissipation of energy of gas causing it to undergo gravitational collapse? Is this a result of the virial theorem? Reduced pressure gradient?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Could you clarify please?

Comment: @honeste_vivere In astrophysics it is claimed that gas in galaxies for example collapse gravitationally when the gas cools. What is the physical mechanism that causes the gas to collapse after it cools?

Comment: I think you just stated that gravity makes the gas collapse?  Or are you trying to ask what makes the gas cool?